# Create custom design in crosstab using crystalreport 9

Tags: crystal-reports

How to create custom design in crosstab using crystal report 9.

For ex : I want to create design like this in crosstab

---

### SiteName      Opening  15    16   17   18     19 .........so on   Total

Ambuja         500     20    80   90    0     20.................. 120

### T-Point        750     50    20   100   10   190.................. 1120

But my task design is coming like this
[image]

So, please give me the hint or any solution that how can I will do the custom design in crosstab using crystal report 9

Thanks In Advance.